# C++ int& operator[](string key) function using Linked List

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

For a comsci project I have been assigned recently, we have to implement our own version of the STL Map using a Linked List. In our operator[] overload function though we cannot figure out how to access and return the "int&".

This is what we have tried doing so far:

```
int& LLMap::operator[](string key){

    //return this->myMap.searchforNodeAddress(key)->getPairValue();


    return this->myMap.searchforNodeAddress(key)->getPairValueAddress();

}
```

And here are the implementations of the functions being called:

```
PairNode* PairLinkedList::searchforNodeAddress(string desiredKey){
    PairNode* currNode = this->getPairHead();
    while (currNode != NULL){
        if (currNode->getPairKey() == desiredKey){
            return currNode;
        }
        else{
            currNode = currNode->getNext();
        }
    }

}
```

And

```
int PairNode::getPairValue(){
    return this->value;
}

int* PairNode::getPairValueAddress(){
    return &(this->value);
}
```

We have been trying to figure this out for quite some time now and are completely stumped, any pointers in the right direction or any assistance at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either dereference the address...

```
return *myMap.searchforNodeAddress(key)->getPairValueAddress();
```

...or change `getPairValue()`...

```
int& PairNode::getPairValue()  // now returns int&
```

Separately, the STL `map` (lowercase "m") is confined to history - you probably mean the C++ Standard Library `std::map`, and you can't strictly "implement" either with a linked list: they're necessarily balanced binary trees, given the Standard's performance guarantees.  You can implement something with a `std::map`-like *interface* - minus those performance characteristics - over a linked list....

Also, prefer to pass `string` parameters that won't be modified inside a function using `const std::string&`: it avoids allocating extra memory and copying the text over, only to release it after the function exits.